# How to implement Tao core PHP LTI 1.3 in my tool?

Tags: moodle, lti

I am new in LTI 1.3 - tao ,so for me this a bit hard to understand how to embed this library into my tool. I also want to understand the code workflow and structure. For LMS, I am using Moodle .

If is there any example code available for this library (https://github.com/oat-sa/lib-lti1p3-core)? My Tool based on PHP Codeigniter, if available for demo purpose, can someone please share me?

I already installed the core library using composer and configured the basic configuration such as keychain, platform details, tool details. Now in registration, I am having some problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a LTI tool from Moodle, then there is an existing activity called "External Tool" - no development is required

Go to a course, switch on editing, add an activity and select external tool

The rest is explained here

https://docs.moodle.org/401/en/External_tool

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But here I want to use my own application as a tool that supports LTI 1.3 login and launch. so using that library I want to make my application handle login and launch.

Comment: Okay, so not related to Moodle?

Comment: Okay so first I will implement this library in my application (as an external tool) to handle LTI 1.3. Then I launch my application from Moodle.